# How does the "--check-updates" parameter of monerod work?

Tags: monerod

The monero daemon has this option:

```
  --check-updates arg (=notify)         Check for new versions of monero:
                                        [disabled|notify|download|update]
```

I tried running my node with `--check-updates update`, but no update/notification takes place.

```
$ ./monero-v0.10.2.1/monerod --check-updates update
```

`status` shows **up to date**.

```
Height: 1275771/1275771 (100.0%) on mainnet, not mining, net hash 57.12 MH/s, v4, up to date, 8(out)+21(in) connections, uptime 0d 23h 59m 3s
```

Is it implemented/working?

If yes, how does it work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `--check-updates` option has four subcommands:

```
update     subcommands: check (check if an update is available), download (download it if there is), update (not implemented)
```

- check: check for updates, but do nothing beyond printing a notification
- download: download any update
- update: run the newly updated version

The last one is not implemented yet, only the first three are at the moment.

When you run `status`, the "up to date" comment does not refer to whether a new version is available: it relies on the timing of last known fork to determine whether there should be an update by the current time. It could be replaced with the new --check-updates method, now that it exists. Feel free to open a bug on https://github.com/monero-project/monero/issues mentioning that fact, and pros and cons may be discussed there.

Comment: so would you run --check updates download --check-updates update in order to downloads and run the update? Or would you run --check-update update to download and run?

Comment: @GingerA `--check-update update` will download new version first before update.

Comment: update download 2023-01-31 XX:XX:XX.XXX E Failed to connect to https://updates.getmonero.org/cli/monero-linux-x64-v0.18.1.2.tar.bz2 Error: Problem fetching info -- How do I update my cli wallet without having to make a new cli client and download again since pruned blockchain cannot be exported and imported elsewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You can run `update check` inside the daemon, and it should return you a status.  If your daemon has a "no two valid DNS checkpoints" error, then the `update` command will not function properly, and you'll receive a `msgwriter` error.

Comment: `unknown command: update check`

Comment: These commands were added in `0.10.3` release.

Answer (score 0):

I can partially answer my question because monerod meanwhile returned this:

```
[P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1121    Version 0.10.3.1 of monero for linux-x64 is available: https://downloads.getmonero.org/cli/monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2, SHA256 hash 8db80f8cc4f80d4106db807432828df730a59eac78972ea81652aa6b9bac04ad
[P2P5]  INFO    global  src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1155    New version downloaded to "./monero-v0.10.2.1/monero-linux-x64-v0.10.3.1.tar.bz2"
[P2P5]  ERROR   updates src/cryptonote_core/cryptonote_core.cpp:1165    Download/update not implemented yet
```

The file exists so `notification` and `download` options are implemented.

`status` still shows "up to date".

---

On my second local node I'm receiving:

```
[P2P9]  WARN    net.dns src/common/dns_utils.cpp:529    WARNING: no two valid MoneroPulse DNS checkpoint records were received
```

And it's 1h 45m without any notify/download messages.